# MarkLogic - mlcp export to a single output file

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, mlcp

MarkLogic version 9.0-6.2

mlcp version 9.0.6

I have a customer collection with each document having a customer root node, as below.

```
<customer>
  <customerId>123</customerId>
  ....
</customer>
```

My need is to export all documents in the collection into one single output file under a new root called customerinfo

```
<customerInfo>
    <customer>
      <customerId>123</customerId>
      ....
    </customer>
    <customer>
      <customerId>456</customerId>
      ....
    </customer>
</customerInfo>
```

Using below code, I am able to export the collection as individual documents under a directory.

```
mlcp.sh export -ssl \
-host localhost \
-port 8010 \
-username uname \
-password pword \
-mode local \
-output_file_path /test/TestFiles/customer \
-collection_filter customer \
-output_type document
```

Is it possible to aggregate output into one single document, under a new root node?

Answer (score 0):

No. mlcp can transform documents during import, but not during export. Merging query results into a single document is fairly simple to do in XQuery, though:

```
xdmp:save('/test/TestFiles/customer/merged.xml',
  <root>{ collection('customer') }</root>
)
```

You could also look into other MarkLogic tools like [corb](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2) or the [Data Movement SDK](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/data-movement-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

ml-gradle has some tasks that use MarkLogic's Data Movement SDK so that you ideally don't need to write any code to do this - https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Exporting-data