# MarkLogic - xdmp.save

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

MarkLogic version - 9.0-6.2

When I try to run below xdmp.save command, I am getting below error

```
xdmp.save('C:\\copyright\\cust.txt',fn.collection('customer'))
```

XDMP-ARGTYPE: xdmp.save("C:\copyright\cust.txt", Sequence(cts.doc("/customer/cust1.json"), cts.doc("/customer/cust2.json"), cts.doc("/customer/cust3.json"), ...)) -- arg2 is not of type Node

I am able to get data successfully from fn.doc expression.

```
xdmp.save('C:\\copyright\\cust.txt',fn.doc('/customer/customer1.json'))
```

Any help on how to pass all the documents in a collection to xdmp.save API?

Comment: Are you trying to aggregate all docs in a collection into one file, or would you like to write them all one by one in a directory on the server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MarkLogic - mlcp export to a single output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621264/marklogic-mlcp-export-to-a-single-output-file)

Comment: Yes, he's asked this question before. Please see my first answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54621355/1226554

Comment: Thanks for the response. Based on the response to my earlier post, I am trying to read a collection of JSON documents and write to a single output file (aggregated). However, when I try fn.collection() to get all the documents, I am getting 'arg2 is not of type Node' error.

Comment: I am able to resolve the error with 
 using xdmp.toJSON().
      
 xdmp.save('C:\\copyright\\cust.json',xdmp.toJSON(fn.collection('registration')))

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `xdmp.save` expects the second parameter to be a single Node, but `fn.collection` returns a Sequence. The simplest solution is to convert the Sequence to an array, which is considered a single node.

```
xdmp.save('C:\\copyright\\cust.txt', fn.collection('customer').toArray())
```